# Compound Operator Implicit Conversion Failing

Tags: c#, type-conversion

This errors:

```
double z;
int? x = 0;
int? y = 0;

z = (double)x -= (double)y;
```

..this does not error:

```
double z;
int? x = 0;
int? y = 0;

double x_con = (double)x;
double y_con = (double)y;

z = x_con -= y_con;
```

Simple question. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If fails on this alone, without the `z`:

```
(double)x -= (double)y;
```

Simply because the left hand side of an assignment operator must be a variable, property or indexer, and not another expression, like your cast is.

Your second example however has the assignment written like this:

```
x_con -= y_con;
```

And that is perfectly fine of course since `x_con` is a variable.

Comment: ok - so assignment operator is the same as compound operator? i.e `-=` ? because this _simple_ operator is fine `(double)x - (double)y; 
`

Comment: `a -= b` is shorthand for `a = a - b;` so in your case that means `(double)x = (double)x - (double)y`. The `(double)x - (double)y` part is just fine, but the assignment `(double)x = ...` is what is giving you the error. The left hand side of = (even when using shorthands like -=, += and so on) can only be a variable, property or indexer in all circumstances.

Comment: thanks ... I'm guessing this is in connection with `=` and `-` having implicit conversion properties themselves; will do some reading around this.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you attempt to perform arithmetic operations on the left hand side of an assignment operator.
see [Statements, Expressions, and Operators (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173142%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information